# tagging package and subfigures: faulty vertical alignment

Tags: line-breaking, subfloats, white-space

I'm using the great tagged package to compile my document using graphics of different qualities and/or file formats. The MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tagging}
\usetag{jpg}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.50\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\textwidth}
        \tagged{png}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b.png}}
        \tagged{jpg}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b.jpg}}
        \tagged{pdf}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b.pdf}}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.50\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\textwidth}
        \tagged{jpg}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b.jpg}}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.50\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\textwidth}
        % just a comment
        \tagged{jpg}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b.jpg}}
        % just a comment
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

will produce:

[image]

As you can see, the mutual vertical alignment concerning the subfigures is somehow broken for the first figure. It seems like `\tagged{png}{...}` and `\tagged{pdf}{...}` leave something in the output stream that causes a misalignment between both of the subfigures. Including only one of the `\tagged` commands (second case) or commenting a line above and below the `\tagged` command in use (third case) will result in the bottom edges of the left/right figures to be aligned perfectly. Any advice on how to further diagnose the issue or fix it is highly appreciated!

Comment: tex does warn you about this: `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 14--16`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not really related to `tagging` you get the same from

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.50\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\textwidth}
        {}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b.jpg}
        {}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.50\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.50\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\textwidth}
        % just a comment
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b.jpg}
        % just a comment
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

the tag omitted graphics are equivalent to `{}` so produce no output but you are not omitting the word spaces that you have on either side.

You end up with a full line with just a word space which produces the warning

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 14--16
```

Commenting out the space removes the Tex warning and fixes the alignment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.50\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\textwidth}
        {}%
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b.jpg}%
        {}%
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.50\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b.jpg}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.50\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\textwidth}
        % just a comment
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b.jpg}
        % just a comment
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```